# Proof in Fitch and counterexample in Tarski's World - From $A \to B$, infer $A \to (B \land C)$.

Tags: logic

Good official morning community,

Strengthening the Consequent: From A→B 
A→B
, infer $A \to (B \land C)$.

I know that this proof is invalid and I want to make a counter example to prove that. How can I write $A \to (B \land C)$ and A→B 
A→B
 in Tarski's World. I tried writing sentences but it keeps telling me that it is of the wrong format.

what I have done so far is that I translated A→B 
A→B
 to tet(a) → 
→
 medium(a)

Would you please help me

Comment: You have to show that from $A \to B$, we cannot infer $A \to (B \land C)$.

Comment: Example: $A= (x \le 4)$, $B= (x \le 5)$ and $C=(x =4)$.

Comment: In the language of "solids" you can try with: $A= \text {Cube}(a) \land \text {Large}(a)$, $B= \text {Cube} (a)$, $C= \text {Cube} (a) \land \text {Small}(a)$.

Comment: It is very simple: $C$ must contradict $A$ or $B$. Try with $C= \lnot Large(a)$

Comment: Maybe $Tet(a) \to Small(a)$ and $Tet(a) \to (Small(a) \land Large(a))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create $1$ object in Tarski's World, make it a small cube, and label it $a$.

Then $Cube(a) \rightarrow Small(a)$ will evaluate to True, and $Cube(a) \rightarrow (Small(a) \land Tet(a))$ will evaluate to False.

Comment: Thank you! That works! But why? I tried a very similar one but without including the tet(a) but it did not work with me.

Comment: I actually feel kind of stupid now, I have been trying this for three consecutive days now.

Comment: @markjohn It works because $Cube(a) \rightarrow Small(a)$ evaluates to $T \rightarrow T=T$, while  $Cube(a) \rightarrow (Small(a) \land Tet(a))$ evaluates to $T \rightarrow (T \land F) = T \rightarrow F=F$. And I'd have to see exactly what you did in order to explain why your earlier attempts did not work .

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you for explaining. I can see why I got them wrong, I was writing the second sentence as Cube(a)V(Small(a) → Cube(a), Which is totally wrong. Are you a teacher?

Comment: @markjohn :) You can find me on page vii)

Comment: page vii -- which book ?

Comment: @markjohn  When doing Fitch, don't forget you now have that nice Add Support Steps feature :)

Comment: @markjohn I just replied to someone else struggling with Fitch proofs ... search for 'Fitch system for Logic Proofs' ... I go through the 'proper' thought process for setting up those proofs... maybe it helps you as well. And don't get discouraged!!

Comment: @markjohn The answer there may not have been accepted, but the answer was perfectly good. Fitch does not have MT (Modus Tollens), but the person that answered showed how to prove the pattern of ModusTollens at the end of the post.

Comment: @markjohn That's a whole new question ... you better make that into a new post.  And when you do so, you should show some of your own attempts, so we can see where you get stuck or confused.